# SharedPreferences to avoid login screen after the first login

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, autologin

I am trying to use SharedPreferences to skip the login Activity: if the login is done already the SharedPreferences will store the user name and the login shall proceed the second time without going through the login Activity.

```
CallbackManager mcallbackManager;
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private String your_user_name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", your_user_name);
    editor.commit();

    if (mPreferences.contains("username")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, getMyLocation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mcallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, getMyLocation.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

        }
}
```

I have used the above code, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
There is no crash in the app while running and nothing is shown in the logcat.

I don't no where I made a mistake.

Comment: What value this `String` `your_user_name` contains ?

Comment: You have not used Shared preference correctly. You should commit with a usename when user login via facebook. And onCreate you just have to check if it contains default value then show login screen else go to next Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't compare string with user name just set one boolean value

on success result of the login make that value to true.

```
sharePrefObje.putBoolean("isLoginKey",true);
```

on your splash screen check like this way

```
 if (getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCENAME",0).getBoolean("isLoginKey",false)){
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }else{
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cant understand what you are saying any chance you could edit the code I have provided.?

Comment: public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, getMyLocation.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

Comment: set isLogin variable to true here so you can do it.,

Comment: can you mail me only single file so that i can edit it and send you back.

Comment: can you give me a mail id or something so I can mail you the set off code's.??

Comment: md.sameerahmed8@gmail.com

Comment: @Sameer I have sent you a mail can you please check it.?